# Order of file selection in Tkinter is not order in python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to make a program which enables comparison of data from selected files in one graph. The order in which they are depcited as well as the distance between them is important. However the order in which I select them in the window created by using Tkinter is not the same as the order in which they are passed to the program. The order in which I have to select them in order to get the correct order is 2, 3, 4, 5, 1 this results in order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the program.

It is not a big problem once you know it but the intention is that others will be using the program as well so I need it to work as simple and robust as possible. Below is the snippet of the code that I use where Tkinter is involved.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
filez = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
filez= root.tk.splitlist(filez)
root.destroy()
```

Comment: you will have to build own `tkFileDialog` which will remember order. Or create dialog which lets you change order of elements on list (after you get all files from `tkFileDialog`).

Answer (score 1):

There are no options for controlling the order in listed in the documentation. Your best bet is to use multiple file selection dialogs one after another.

Answer (score 1):

`tkFileDialog` doesn't have function to remeber order of selected files so you can build own `FileDialog` or...

... build some Dialog to select order of files after you get files from `tkFileDialog`

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog


def Selector(data):

    def append(widget, element, results, display):
        # append element to list 
        results.append(element)

        # disable button
        widget['state'] = 'disabled'

        # add element to label
        current = display['text']
        if current:
            current += '\n'
        display['text'] = current + element


    # create window 
    root = tk.Tk()

    # list for correct order
    results = []

    # label to display order
    tk.Label(root, text='ORDER').pack()
    l = tk.Label(root, anchor='w', justify='left')
    l.pack(fill='x')

    # buttons to select elements
    tk.Label(root, text='SELECT').pack()

    for d in data:
        b = tk.Button(root, text=d, anchor='w')
        b['command'] = lambda w=b, e=d, r=results, d=l:append(w, e, r, d)
        b.pack(fill='x')

    # button to close window
    b = tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy)
    b.pack(fill='x', pady=(15,0))

    # start mainloop
    root.mainloop()

    return results

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
filez = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
root.destroy()
print(filez)

filez = Selector(filez)
print(filez)
```

Comment: I have been to fast with my comment... While the results of the code as stand alone look great the resulting list is empty. This might be because the program continues while the select window is open so it runs into errors before a order can be defined.

Comment: in example `mailoop()` (iniside `Selector`) doesn't let program continue run. It has to wait till you close window with selection. If you have other windows in your code then it will need modifications.

Comment: I have no more windows that I am aware of. The order in which filez is printed is the one they are selected in, it is also printed before the selection is made. If the code does work as above and as output prints the output in the correct order after selection on your system, could it be and editor or version specific details that prevents it from working as it should in my case?

Comment: I don't thing that editor can change it. Only difference can be if you run different code and you don't assign value returned by `Selection()` to `filez`. Or you doesn't use buttons in Selection() to change order.